Jasmine-Karma how to include ESM module when using Karma Test Explorer
I am using Karma Test Explorer extension for running and debugging tests in VScode.
I have an angular project which is workspace project and in projects/ folder there is a "library" project and "application" project. This "application" project is dependent on the library.
When I am running all of the Angular tests of the "application" project using 'ng test' I get no errors.
If I try to run the tests using the extension I get an error:
./projects/applicationProject/src/app/components/customcomponent.ts - Error: Module not found: Error can't resolve "library-project".
For some reason I can't run the tests using this extension. I have even tried to create a custom configuration using karma.conf.js and defining the dependency in there:
files: [
{ pattern: 'path/to/library/*.mjs' type: 'module'}
]

but the issue is that I am compiling to ESM and karma-runner does not support it to my understanding so I can't include .mjs or .ts files.
My goal is to run tests from Vscode and debug them in Angular workspace consisting of many projects.
